# How do I write query to get record that are created one week ago in JPA

Tags: java, mysql, sql, date, spring-data-jpa

In the following repository I want to get those records (Orders) that are placed one week ago , I am using the following code but error is occurred and said unexpected token at interval So Anybody help me?

```
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long> {
    @Query("Select Order where orderDate < SQL((? - interval '3' minute), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)")
    Order currentOrder();

    // I also tried following query 
    @Query("Select Order  where orderDate > NOW() - interval 1 WEEK")
    Order currentOrder();
}
```

Comment: What happened when you ran the second query, which looks like it should work?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  it gives an error 
unexpected token: interval near line 1, column 41 [Select Order  where orderDate > NOW() - interval 1 WEEK]

Comment: Apart from the fact that "SQL" and NOW" are invalid JPQL, so you would have to use a native query?

Comment: @NeilStockton What should I use then ?

Comment: @android Just use a regular JPQL query in your actual code, not a named query.  Then you can set whatever dates you wish, from Java.

Answer (score 0):

JPA doesn't have much in the way of support for date functions, so you might not be able to get the behavior you want from a named query.

However, a regular JPQL query should work because there we can bind whatever date we want.  Try the following:

```
public List findOrdersLastWeek() {
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -7);
    Date lastWeekDate = cal.getTime();        

    return entityManager.createQuery(
       "SELECT o from Orders o WHERE o.orderDate > ?1")
      .setParameter(1, lastWeekDate, TemporalType.DATE);
}
```

Comment: what is 1 in setParameter ?

Comment: The first (and only) parameter is a Java `Date` corresponding to one week ago.

Answer (score 0):

your answer should be like that

List findByUserAndCreatedAtBetween(User user, String todayString, String sevenDaysBeforeString);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).